# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Javascript/Jquery form issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting the following error generated when I complete the email input field of my sign up form. I can't see why this is happening, I've tried removing form validation etc and it still occurs.

Does anyone know of nay issues with jquery and form entry? I can't see why I'm getting an undefined message as the js should capture the email field from

```
Email = $('#emailsu').val();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedn.extend.each @ jquery.js:348(anonymous function) @
>   jqBootstrapValidation.js:458n.extend.each @ jquery.js:374n.fn.n.each @
>   jquery.js:139(anonymous function) @
>   jqBootstrapValidation.js:456n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4435r.handle
>   @ jquery.js:4121
>       skitch.js:9 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled' is deprecated. Please use
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled' instead.

My html is

```
 <div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="emailsu" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
   <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
          </div>
```

and my JS is

```
function UserSignUp() {

    var user = new Parse.User();
    userFirstname = $('#firstnamesu').val();
    userLastname = $('#lastnamesu').val();
    userUsername = $('#usernamesu').val();
    userGender = $('#gendersu').val();
    Email = $('#emailsu').val();
    PWP = $('#passwordsu').val();

    user.set("FirstName", userFirstname);
    user.set("LastName", userLastname);
    user.set("username", userUsername);
    user.set("gender", userGender);
    user.set("email", Email);
    user.set("password", PWP);


   var fileUploadControl = $("#pic")[0];
   if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
   var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
   var name = "photo.png";

   var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

   //put this inside if {
   parseFile.save().then(function() {
   // The file has been saved to Parse.
   }, function(error) {
   // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });

    // Be sure of ur parameters name
    // user is extend of my class in parse 
    user.set("ProfilePic", parseFile);
    user.save();
   }
```

Comment: if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) here is the error. proof for .files first else u get the error

Comment: 2 suggestions: do you waut until the DOM is ready? Is the requested value really in the `value=` attribute at that moment?

Comment: @LiviuBoboia So this means that the user needs to add a file first before trying to add their email address, thats what you are saying? Even if I add I file I still get the same error. Happy to accept the answer if you can illustrate?

Comment: well that part works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9nhkafk7/

Comment: @Thomas with every other field there is'nt an issue so I expected the DOM to be ready. Not sure I understand your second point?

Comment: Your error is about `length`, the only code that can trigger it is `fileUploadControl.files.length`, so your searching in the wrong direction. There is nothing wrong with your email stuff.

Comment: @BasvanStein I can't understand how that can be, I deleted the js file of the server and removed the code you mentioned above. I still get the same error :-/

Comment: are you sure that variable is not null?